# How to install linq.js in Asp.net Core Web Application (.net framework) and how to use it?

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, bower, linq.js

We are developing an `Asp.net Core Web Application (.net framework)`.
I want to use [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) in this new project.

**[Bower](https://bower.io/)** is giving many same name options but does not seems to be the desired version, as description and version is different from
the the one which is [on CodePlex and on NugetGet](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/).

I am triyng to install current ver 2.2.0.2

Earlier in `asp.net 5`, I have used `Nuget Package Manager` to install this js library. I have also tried to install using `Nuget Package Manager` in this .net core project also. It is installing the `linq.js` sucessfully in .net core project also.

`Restoring packages for c:\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/linq.js/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/linq.js/index.json 940ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js.2.2.0.2.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js.2.2.0.2.nupkg 952ms
Installing linq.js 2.2.0.2.
Installing NuGet package linq.js 2.2.0.2.
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: c:\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 2856.451ms for c:\WebApplication1\src\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj.
Successfully installed 'linq.js 2.2.0.2' to WebApplication1
Executing nuget actions took 4.41 sec
========== Finished ==========
Time Elapsed: 00:00:07.5474751`

But I do see not any `linq.js` files in my project, not sure how to install `linq.js` in `.net core project` using any of the `package manager`, as I do not want to do it manually.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: I had a problem with bower, giving me wrong versions and sometimes files were missing as well, I'd attempt using Node, try `npm install linq` in your cmd, this should create a node_module folder with the library in there which you can use. Note: it might be hidden.

Comment: @AntonToshik, thanks for your valuable suggestion, this seems to be a good option.